# "ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 10 column 11 (char 357)"

Tags: python, json

Hey I've got a little problem. I want to make a weather station on a Raspberry Pi 3B (school project).

Here's the log:

```
     Logger initialization started Check if directory for storing logs is writeable Directory is writeable Logger initialized 
02-05-18 23:45:41 INFO root DHT22logger execution started 
02-05-18 23:45:41 INFO Configurations.ConfigHandler ConfigHandler instantiation started 
02-05-18 23:45:41 INFO Configurations.ConfigHandler Instantiate ConfigReader 02-05-18 23:45:41 INFO Configurations.ConfigReader ConfigReader instantiation started 
02-05-18 23:45:41 INFO Configurations.ConfigReader Loading configurations from config.json 
02-05-18 23:45:41 ERROR Configurations.ConfigHandler Instantiation failed 
02-05-18 23:45:41 ERROR root Failed to get configurations: Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "DHT22logger.py", line 58, in main
    configurationHandler = ConfigHandler()   File "/home/pi/DHT22-TemperatureLogger/Configurations/ConfigHandler.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.configReader = ConfigReader()   File "/home/pi/DHT22-TemperatureLogger/Configurations/ConfigReader.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.configurations = json.loads(open(configurationFile).read())   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx) ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 10 column 11 (char 357)
```

I can't find anything wring in the config file:

```
    {
"mysql":[{
        "host":"localhost",
        "user":"[username]",
        "password":"[password]",
        "database":"[database]"
        }],
"sensors":
        [[{"name":"TEMP"},{"gpio":"4"},{"sensorType":"22"},{"temperatureLowLimit":"0"},{"temperatureHighLimit":"25"},{"temperatureThreshold":"5"},{"humidityLowLimit":"30"},{"humidityHighLimit":"60"},{"humidityThreshold":"10"}],
"mailInfo":[{
        "senderaddress":"[MAIL]@gmail.com",
        "receiveraddress":"[MAIL]@gmail.com",
        "username":"[USER]",
        "password":"[PASSWORD]",
        "subjectmessage":"Info von RasPi WeatherStation",
        "subjectwarning":"Warnung von RasPi WeatherStation"
        }],
"sqlBackupDump":[{
        "backupDumpEnabled":"y",
        "backupDay":"3",
        "backupHour":"17",
        "backupDumpPath":"/home/pi/DHT22-TemperatureLogger/Backups/"
        }],
"weeklyAverages":[{
        "weeklyAverageSendingEnabled":"y",
        "weekDayForSendingAverages":"3",
        "hourOfTheDayForSendingAverages":"16"
        }],
"useFahrenheits":"n",
"mailSendingTimeoutInFullHours":"1",
"adafruitPath":"/home/pi/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/AdafruitDHT.py"
}
```

The part that the error indicates is the colon behind mailInfo.

Btw. I am using a tutorial by jjpfin, which was made almost 3 years ago.
[The Tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-PI-and-DHT22-temperature-and-humidity-lo/)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The value of `sensors` is a array, whose first element is an array, and whose second element is `"mailInfo": …`. But that can't go inside a array, only inside an object.

Comment: If you're writing JSON manually, it may help to use a nice syntax-highlighting editor. Most of the same editors that are good for source code (whether you like Atom or emacs) are also good for JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid because you are missing a `]` character. Replace this line

```
[[{"name":"TEMP"},{"gpio":"4"},{"sensorType":"22"},{"temperatureLowLimit":"0"},{"temperatureHighLimit":"25"},{"temperatureThreshold":"5"},{"humidityLowLimit":"30"},{"humidityHighLimit":"60"},{"humidityThreshold":"10"}],
```

with this

```
[[{"name":"TEMP"},{"gpio":"4"},{"sensorType":"22"},{"temperatureLowLimit":"0"},{"temperatureHighLimit":"25"},{"temperatureThreshold":"5"},{"humidityLowLimit":"30"},{"humidityHighLimit":"60"},{"humidityThreshold":"10"}]],
```

A useful tool for the future, and the one that I used to check your problem is [JSONlint](https://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Good answer. The clue for finding this error was in your log " ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 10 column 11". This often happens with parens/brackets/braces errors -- Python barfs sometime after where the closing bracket should have been. Using a code editor that highlights parens, you can go backwards and make sure all of your parens/brackets/braces are close.